# Trying to edit string using .replace with Python

Tags: python, replace

I have a string:

```
some_string = "I rode my bike 100' North toward the train station"
```

I want to change the (' North ) part to (' N ), so that that part reads as (...my bike 100' N toward the...) etc.

Write now I'm trying:

```
some_string = some_string.replace("' North ", "' N ")
```

But it just stays the same.

I don't want to use anything tricky like .replace('orth', '') because I want it to work with longer sentences that might include instances of 'North' but no apostrophe nearby.

Why isn't my first method working?

Please help!

EDIT:

So I am getting that first string by searching within another string.

Python, for some reason, returns it so that the apostrophe is a different kind of apostrope!!? To distinguish it from the single quotes that are not escaped.

```
some_string = '’'
```

^ It looks like that (copied and pasted it). Where does that come from? How would I type it out using my keyboard? Wtf!

EDIT 2:

I am getting the first string from Adobe PDF. I think it is formatted as a "fancy quote" that you get by holding down Alt and typing 0146 on number pad!!!

Comment: are you assigning the replacement to a new variable?

Comment: The string `.replace()` method returns a _new_ string; it does not modify the existing string.

Comment: https://repl.it/@codeguru/GentleFrigidShell Your code works fine for me.

Comment: Where are you getting the strange apostrophe from? Are you copy/pasting from Word or some other word processor? It looks like you are getting a "smart quote".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python (and generally in most high level programming language), `string` are immutable. You can not change it. Indeed, you can produce another string.

So, to achieve your goal, here is my suggestion:

```
some_string = "I rode my bike 100' North toward the train station"
some_string = some_string.replace("' North ", "' N ") # assign the new string to the old string
print(some_string)
```

> **Output:** `"I rode my bike 100' N toward the train station"`

Comment: Ok. So, do you achieve your goal ?

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, meaning they can't be changed; likewise, this method returns a new string, it does not edit in place. You simply need to assign the code you already have to a variable. You can even assign the output of your code above to the same variable, such that the variable name now points to a different string (i.e. the one you want.)

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you assign a new variable.

```
some_string = "I rode my bike 100' North toward the train station"
new_string = some_string.replace("North ", " N ")
print(new_string)
>> I rode my bike 100'  N toward the train station
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
some_string=some_string.replace("' North ", "' N ")
```

instead.

Note that there is a documentation, https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html, telling

> **str.replace(old, new[, count])**
>   Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

---

I call bs on that edit, it works properly, see https://ideone.com/8Mossq

```
some_string = "I rode my bike 100' North toward the train station"
some_string = some_string.replace("' North ", "' N ")
print(some_string)
```

Result:

> ```
> I rode my bike 100' N toward the train station
> ```